# Notation for sum/product over 1-bits in binary representation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

Is there a notation, which indicates that an operation (sum/product/etc) should be taken over the 1-bits in a number $x$'s binary representation, i.e. those powers of $2$ that when summed up equal $x$?

Actually the question is not specific to base $2$, a notation for any base would great, but it was easier formulating it this way.

**Edit** to explain it in more detail:

Let's consider the number $x = 5$, it's binary representation is $101$. Now if I would want to take a sum involving these powers of two I could write
$$\sum_{\substack{i\\i^{th} \text{ bit in binary representation of x is 1}}  }2^i = x$$

The question is essentially if there's a less cumbersome way of defining such a sum.
And **if yes**, if there is there a way to generalize it to higher bases.

Comment: Is your question to sum the bits in a binary number?  For example if $x=5_{10}=101_2$ then $f(x)=2$ (two bits are one).  If so, express $x$ as a vector and take the dot product with a vector of all ones.

Comment: No, I mean a sum running over the exponents

Comment: So, do you want $x=\sum_i b_i 2^{b_i}$, where $x=b_n b_{n-1} \cdots b_1 b_0$?

Comment: Yes, simply a notation which indicates: this sum/product/etc runs over b's exponents of x's representation in base b. For any base > 2 this would also have to include the digit values (in base 2 they are always 1)

Comment: Actually, I posted an answer, but then deleted it.  I cannot seem to understand what it is you are looking for.  Do you want to sum the bits (or sum the digits) in a binary (some other base) representation of an integer?  In your example, what should the sum be calculated as?  2?  Could you give another example?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there’s any standard notation for this. One possibility that’s clunky but not wordy is this: $$\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{i\in{\mathbb Z^+\cup \{0\}}\\\left(\lfloor{x\over 2^i}\rfloor\!\!\!\!\mod\!\!2\right)=1}  }{\text {(summand)}}.$$ You can change the $2$ and $1$ for the particular base and digit you want. If I were to put something like this in a paper, I would explain it in sentences before the first use, and possibly make up a notation like $\text{digit}_{base\ n}(x,i)$ so it’s easier for the reader to remember the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , normal operations like addition , multiplication etc.are not base specific(However there are operations which are meaningful for certain base like Exclusive OR).You will get the same result if you take care of the base your numbers are in.The numbers in specific base have their notation,like a binary no. is denoted by $a_2$,but there is no need for notation for operation.$11_2 + 100_2=111$ is equivalent to $3_{10}+4_{10}=7_{10}$

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I've edited it and hope it is clearer now.